# system with parameter $m$

Tags: equations, systeme

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathdots}
\begin{document}
Soit $m$ un nombre r\'eel. On consid\`ere le syst\`eme lin\'eaire suivant:
\begin{equation*}
(S):\left\{
      \begin{aligned}
-2y+z &=1 \\
mx- 3y+mz &=0\\
mx-2y &=2
          \end{aligned}
           \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a nicer way to write it?

Comment: what is your question? do you want a nicer input syntax or nicer typeset output. "nice" is a very personal thing, what exactly do you want to change?

Comment: yes a nicer and more clear typeset output if possible since it is an exam for students

Comment: we can not guess what you consider nice (personally I  would drop the `{` but I am not French)

Comment: may the ''='' are not paralel will be better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the [systeme](/questions/tagged/systeme) tag: that's about the `systeme` package ([documentation in French](https://texdoc.org/serve/systeme/0)).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathdots}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

Soit $m$ un nombre réel. On considère le système linéaire suivant:
\begin{equation*}
(S):
\systeme[xyz]{
  -2y+z = 1,
  mx- 3y+mz = 0,
mx-2y = 2
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Since we want that *m* is considered as a parameter, we need to tell explicitly what the unknowns are.

[image]

Direct input of accented letters has worked for a long time.

If you prefer left alignment, you were almost on the right track.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathdots}

\begin{document}

Soit $m$ un nombre réel. On considère le système linéaire suivant:
\begin{equation*}
(S):
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  & {-}2y+z = 1 \\
  & mx- 3y+mz = 0 \\
  & mx-2y = 2
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note `{-}` in order to make it a unary symbol rather than an operation symbol.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Professor @egreg. If I would like to have the "=" signs not parallel, what modifications should I make to the code? It would be great if you could include the solution in your answer for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: What do you mean by “not parallel”? Everything with left alignment?

Comment: that is not align professor. That is -2y+z=1. There is no extra spaces

Comment: @Student Sorry, but I can't understand. See the edited answer, though.

Comment: your edit is great Professor

Comment: In your opinion what is better the first or second answer? it is an exam for my students. I want the more clear version. I guess it is the first. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Student I'd go with the first version.

Comment: Note that something similar like `\systeme` provides OpTeX too. The name is `\eqsystem`, see https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/math-doc.pdf, section 6.